# React Native Expo: Placing a Camera inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I need to put a Camera ("expo-camera") view inside a horizontal viewPager ("@react-native-community/viewpager").
I can't get it to work.

I was able to place other components with no problem, and I was able to show the Camera as a stand alone view.
I'm still a beginner.
Is this possible?
If so, can someone make a simple template of these two components together please?

ViewPager:

```js
import React from "react";

import ViewPager from "@react-native-community/viewpager";

import Record from "../../components/Record";

import { View } from "react-native";

const Home: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <ViewPager
      onPageSelected={(event) => {
        //Nothing yet
      }}
      style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#000" }}
      orientation="horizontal"
      scrollEnabled={true}
    >
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#f54242" }} />
      <Record isFeed={false} />
    </ViewPager>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Camera:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";

const Record: React.FC = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState<boolean | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function permission(): Promise<void> {
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status === "granted");
      StatusBar.setHidden(true);
    }
    permission();
  }, []);

  if (hasPermission === null) {
    return <View />;
  }
  if (hasPermission === false) {
    return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <Camera type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}/>
  );
};

export default Record;
```

Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: Can't get it to work meaning there's an error or it doesn't show? Please provide more details :) Edit: I am asking this because. if the case is it doesn't show -- then maybe you just need to change the size of the camera component (e.g. flex: 1).

Comment: Yup, it wasn't showing. Removing the Flex from both views fixed it. I now am getting an issue where the preview freezes on first frame.

Comment: Great. I think the freeze is another issue. Are you using a real device or an emulator?

Comment: Real device (iPhone 7), I believe the Camera component doesn't work on emulators. I edited the question to show code.

Comment: <Camera
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
 
        ref={ref => (camera = ref)}
        type='front'
        onFacesDetected={handleFacesDetected}   
             FaceDetectorSettings = {{
          mode: FaceDetector.Constants.Mode.fast,
          detectLandmarks: FaceDetector.Constants.Landmarks.none,
          runClassifications: FaceDetector.Constants.Classifications.none,
          minDetectionInterval: 5000,
          tracking: false
        }}
      ></Camera>

Comment: Can you try with these properties?

Comment: Hmm. I think I came across a very similar issue with expo-camera. Basically you have to re-render it on page focus, and  unload it on page blur.  I implemented it using tabs (react-navigation 5). There might be a similar concept in ViewPager but I haven't checked deeply.  Basically the idea is, if page is focused = render camera, on exit of focus = dont render camera.

Comment: Check out the 2nd answer in this one, it will give you the idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58575757/expo-camera-preview-component-started-displaying-black-screen-out-of-the-blue